# Imprimir la serie 1, 2, 5, 26, 677... en C++

Tags: c++

El ejercicio consiste en mostrar los 20 primeros numeros de la serie 1, 2, 5 ,26, 677...

La Formula seria la siguiente: 1 * 1=1+1=2, 2 * 2=4+1=5... (a*a+1)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int aux=0;

   for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
       cout<<aux+1<<endl;
       aux=i*i;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

pero me muestra numeros de mas y no lograr continuar la serie.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero dejarme entender.

Comment: pon tu codigo como texto, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Tú estás poniendo la fórmula `a * a + 1`, sin embargo  estás sigueindo otra fómula muy distinta `aux = i * i`

Comment: Recuerda que al hacer `aux + 1` no modifica su valor realmente, bastaría con cambiarlo por `aux` y abajo no sería multiplicar `i` sino `aux *= aux + 1`

Comment: si lo se, pero eso no afectara el resultado final.

Comment: Ahorita lo que estás haciendo es imprimir `i * i + 1`. Fíjate que se imprime `(1^2 + 1), (2^2 + 1), (3^2 + 1) ... (19^2 + 1)` entonces...

Comment: Yo veo que el código funciona como describes (salvo que la serie del título no coincide con la serie de la fórmula) ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? ¿Qué esperabas obtener?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con esto:

```
aux=aux*aux+1;
```

en vez de esto:

```
aux=i*i;
```

Sin embargo, el resultado va a crecer demasiado rápido (va a explotar).

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que es más fácil hacer primero la operación de asignación con la fórmula, y luego imprimes el valor calculado. En tu código imprimes el valor del contador al cuadrado +1, pero no asignas ese uno al aux.

Comment: Sí, creo que el código quedaría más claro así